# Intelligence server configuration and libeay32.dll registration error! (Microstrategy)

Tags: windows-server-2003, regsvr32

I am trying to configure the Microstrategy Intelligence Server on a Windows Server 2003 Small Business Server.

When I login while configuring, it gives me the error:

> The ORDINAL 2821 could not be located
>   in the dynamic link library
>   LIBEAY32.dll

After much searching, it seems that the error is with the `libeay32.dll` file - either a newer version is needed or the current DLL is not registered.

When I tried to register the DLL with the command:

```
regsvr32 libeay32.dll
```

I got the error:

> DllRegistryServer EntryPoint not
>   found.

Any ideas? My aim is to configure the Microstrategy Intelligence Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your answer. Tested on hardware, not VM. I'm new to Windows Server, from Linux. Problems like this remind me why I left Microsoft products in the 90's....

Here's the link where I found the answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KD5RVG7CKCA

What I had happening was a corrupt .dll file. RE-REGISTERING IS THE KEY, because the registry attempt fails due to the file already being registered.

Re-Registering All DLLs

1. Understand how this method works. By creating a list of your computer's DLL files and running the list as a BAT file, you can automatically register all of your computer's DLL files. This is optimal if you don't have a specific DLL that you want to register.
2. Open Start. Click the Windows logo in the bottom-left corner of the screen.
3. Search for Command Prompt. Type command prompt into the Start search bar. You should see the Command Prompt icon appear at the top of the window.
4. Open Command Prompt in administrator mode. To do so: 
       ◦ Right-click Command Prompt. 
       ◦ Click Run as administrator 
       ◦ Click Yes when prompted.
5. Switch to the Windows directory. Type in cd c:\Windows and press ↵ Enter. This will tell Command Prompt to execute the next command inside of the "Windows" folder.
6. Create a DLL list file. Type dir *.dll /s /b > C:\regdll.bat into Command Prompt, then press ↵ Enter. Doing so allows Command Prompt to create a file listing the location and name of every DLL in the Windows directory.
7. Close Command Prompt. Once you see the "c:\Windows>" line of text appear below the command you entered, you're free to exit Command Prompt and proceed.
8. Go to the list file's location. You can find it from within File Explorer:

   - Open File Explorer (or press ⊞ Win+E).
   - Click This PC on the left side of the window.
   - Double-click your computer's OS (C:) hard drive. 
     Scroll down (if necessary) until you see a file named "regdll".
9. Copy the file onto your desktop. In order to save your changes, you'll need to place a copy of the "regdll" file on your desktop:

   - Click the file once to select it.
   - Press Ctrl+C.
   - Click the desktop.
   - Press Ctrl+V.
10. Open the list file in Notepad. Click the file on your desktop once to select it, then do the following:

    - Right-click the "regdll" file.
    - Click Edit in the drop-down menu.
11. Remove unnecessary DLL locations. While optional, completing this step will cut down significantly on the amount of time it takes to register the DLL files. You can delete any lines of text which have the following locations:[2]

    - C:\Windows\WinSXS — The bottom quarter or so of the text document will contain these lines of text.
    - C:\Windows\Temp — You'll find these near the section where the "WinSXS" lines were.
    - C:\Windows\$patchcache$ — These are harder to find. You can run a search by pressing Ctrl+F, typing in $patchcache$, and clicking Find next.
12. Add the "regsvr" command to each line of text. You can do this by using Notepad's "Find and Replace" feature:

    - Click Edit.
    - Click Replace... in the drop-down menu.
    - Type c:\ into the "Find what" text box.
    - Type Regsvr32.exe /s c:\ into the "Replace with" text box.
    - Click Replace All
    - Exit the window.
13. Save your changes and exit Notepad. Press Ctrl+S to save your changes, then click the X in the top-right corner of the Notepad window to close it. At this point, you're ready to run the "regdll.bat" file.
14. Run the file. Right-click the "regdll.bat" file, click Run as administrator, and click Yes when prompted to run it in Command Prompt. Doing so will allow Command Prompt to begin registering every available DLL; this process can take a long time to complete, so just make sure your computer is on and plugged in for the duration.
15. Exit Command Prompt. Once the process finishes running, you can close Command Prompt. Your computer's DLL files should now be registered.
    Windows Resource protection – check integrity of system files:

command prompt window as administrator:

```
$ cd \windows\system32
$ sfc /scannow
```

Repair Corrupt or Damaged Files

Online using Windows Update:

```
$ dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

Using Installation DVD:

```
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:D:\
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a search for all the copies of libeay32.dll on your system, starting at the root of C:, rename all copies to something like libeay32.dl! to get them out of the way (might need to boot into safe mode for this) and then make sure that you end up with a single copy of the latest (by date) version of the dll in %SystemRoot%\system32 (probably C:\windows\system32), reboot and try again.

Comment: trying that, but there is only 1 copy of the file!! no other copies were found on the system. :/

Answer (score 0):

`libeay32.dll` is most likely part of [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/).  It's not a COM library that would need registered with `revsgr32`, but rather a regular code library.  It's also normally paired up with `ssleay32.dll`.  You can find the latest windows binaries at [Shining Light Productions](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), but it's not a guarantee that they'll work with that product.

The best thing to do in this case is get in contact with the vendor and ask them about it -- these are libraries that should have been bundled with and deployed with the application.